# Ansible Assert Module

Tags: module, ansible, network-programming

I am trying to use assert module in Ansible.
Getting the following error:

> fatal: [S1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ip routing' in
>   print_output.stdout_lines' failed. The error was: template error while
>   templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got
>   'routing'. String: {% if ip routing' in print_output.stdout_lines %}
>   True {% else %} False {% endif %}"}

I am basically trying to do checks if my static route has been added to the config. Thanks in advance for any suggestions. Here's my playbook:

```
---

### Here I am trying to use assert on the file which was saved in a file

# Here we basically moving username and password to yaml_demo

- name: Take global command
  hosts: S1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - /home/patryk/Ansible-GNS3/default_route/yaml_demo.yaml
#./yaml_demo.yaml - if it's in the same location

  vars_prompt:
   # - name: USERNAME
   #   prompt: "Please put your username"
   #   private: no
   # - name: DEVICE_PASSWORD
   #   prompt: "Please put your password"
   #   private: yes


    - name: NEXT_HOP
      prompt: "Please enter the IP of the Next HOP"
      private: no


  tasks:
  - name: Add default route
    eos_config:
      provider:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ USERNAME }}"
        password: "{{ DEVICE_PASSWORD }}"
        use_ssl: no
        authorize: yes
        transport: cli
      lines:
        - "ip route 0.0.0.0/0 {{ NEXT_HOP }}"

  - name: INPUT SHOW COMMAND TO DEVICES
    eos_command:
        commands: "show run"
        provider:
          host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          username: "{{ USERNAME }}"
          password: "{{ DEVICE_PASSWORD }}"
          use_ssl: no
          authorize: yes
          transport: cli
    register: print_output

  - name: OUTPUT SHOW COMMAND to SCREEN
    debug:
        msg: "{{ print_output.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: OUTPUT SHOW COMMAND to FILE
    copy: content="{{ print_output.stdout[0] }}" dest="./output/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"

  - name: Get the whole config FILE
    command: cat ./output/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt

  - name: Assert that the config was pushed succesfully
    assert:
       that:
          - "'ip route 0.0.0.0/0 {{ NEXT_HOP }},' in {{ inventory_hostname }}.txt.stdout_lines"
       success_msg: "Yes it has been pushed"
       fail_msg: "It's not there!"
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. The failing conditional check mentioned in your error is not anywhere in your example playbook. Are you sure you pasted the good playbook and/or error? Besides that please take some time to read [How to create an MCVE](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and try to restrict your example to a minimum data set and failing task(s) that anyone could easily play on its own machine to help you solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As is **very clearly** stated in the error message, you are missing an opening quote:

```
{% if ip routing' in print_output.stdout_lines %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}
```

YAML does not enforce matching quotes, so this outputs the characters `"a", "b", "c", "'"`:

```yaml
- debug:
   msg: abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have a working script now below:

```
---

### Here I am trying to use assert on the file which was saved in a file

# Here we basically moving username and password to yaml_demo

- name: Take global command
  hosts: S1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - /home/patryk/Ansible-GNS3/default_route/yaml_demo.yaml
#./yaml_demo.yaml - if it's in the same location

  vars_prompt:
   # - name: USERNAME
   #   prompt: "Please put your username"
   #   private: no
   # - name: DEVICE_PASSWORD
   #   prompt: "Please put your password"
   #   private: yes


    - name: NEXT_HOP
      prompt: "Please enter the IP of the Next HOP"
      private: no


  tasks:
  - name: Add default route
    eos_config:
      provider:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ USERNAME }}"
        password: "{{ DEVICE_PASSWORD }}"
        use_ssl: no
        authorize: yes
        transport: cli
      lines:
        - "ip route 0.0.0.0/0 {{ NEXT_HOP }}"

  - name: INPUT SHOW COMMAND TO DEVICES
    eos_command:
        commands: "show run"
        provider:
          host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          username: "{{ USERNAME }}"
          password: "{{ DEVICE_PASSWORD }}"
          use_ssl: no
          authorize: yes
          transport: cli
    register: print_output

  - name: OUTPUT SHOW COMMAND to SCREEN
    debug:
        msg: "{{ print_output.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: OUTPUT SHOW COMMAND to FILE
    copy: content="{{ print_output.stdout[0] }}" dest="./output/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"

  - name: Get the whole config FILE
    command: cat ./output/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt
    register: postcheck

  - name: Assert that the config was pushed succesfully
    assert:
       that:
          - "'ip route 0.0.0.0/0 {{ NEXT_HOP }}' in postcheck.stdout_lines"
       success_msg: "Yes it has been pushed"
       fail_msg: "It's not there!"
```

But not sure why almost exactly the same script doesn't work:

```
---

### Here I am trying to use assert directly after printing output without saving to a file

# Here we basically moving username and password to yaml_demo

- name: Take global command
  hosts: S1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - /home/patryk/Ansible-GNS3/default_route/yaml_demo.yaml
#./yaml_demo.yaml - if it's in the same location

#  vars_prompt:
   # - name: USERNAME
   #   prompt: "Please put your username"
   #   private: no
   # - name: DEVICE_PASSWORD
   #   prompt: "Please put your password"
   #   private: yes


    #- name: NEXT_HOP
    #  prompt: "Please enter the IP of the Next HOP"
  #    private: no


  tasks:
  - name: Add default route
    eos_config:
      provider:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ USERNAME }}"
        password: "{{ DEVICE_PASSWORD }}"
        use_ssl: no
        authorize: yes
        transport: cli
  #    lines:
  #      - "ip route 0.0.0.0/0 {{ NEXT_HOP }}"

  - name: INPUT SHOW COMMAND TO DEVICES
    eos_command:
        commands: "show vlan"
        provider:
          host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          username: "{{ USERNAME }}"
          password: "{{ DEVICE_PASSWORD }}"
          use_ssl: no
          authorize: yes
          transport: cli
    register: print_output

  - name: OUTPUT SHOW COMMAND to SCREEN
    debug:
      msg: "{{ print_output.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: Assert that ip route 0.0.0.0/0 55.5.5.5 is there
    assert:
      that:
         - "'ip route 0.0.0.0/0 5.5.5.5' in print_output.stdout_lines"
      success_msg: "Yes it has been pushed"
      fail_msg: "It's not there!"



  # - name: OUTPUT SHOW COMMAND to SCREEN
  #   debug:
  #       msg: "{{ print_output.stdout_lines }}"

  # - name: Get the whole SW1.txt file
  #   command: cat /home/patryk/Ansible-GNS3/default_route/output/S1.txt
  #   register: SW1_config
```

Getting the following error:

```
fatal: [S1]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "'ip route 0.0.0.0/0 5.5.5.5' in print_output.stdout_lines", 
    "changed": false, 
    "evaluated_to": false, 
    "msg": "It's not there!"
}
```

Just want to make the script shorter so no point of saving to a file and then read from it. Would rather read from it straight away without saving it